# Combinations of Variables in R

Tags: r, variables, combinations, permutation, expand

I'm trying to create a fake data frame to examine the effects from a multinomial logit model in R. I have code that does precisely what I want to do, wich is to create a row representing every combination of levels of different variables.

```
var1 <- seq(1,10,1)
var2 <- seq(1,20,5)

FakeData <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow=length(var1) * length(var2),
                                 ncol=2))

row <- 1
for(i in 1:length(var1)){
  for(j in 1:length(var2)){
    FakeData[row, 1] <- var1[i] 
    FakeData[row, 2] <- var2[j]
    row <- row + 1
  }
}


> head(FakeData)
  V1 V2
1  1  1
2  1  6
3  1 11
4  1 16
5  2  1
6  2  6
```

My problem is that this code is very inefficient when applied to my problem with four variables of around ten levels each. Any tips on functions that might make it quicker?

Comment: Every *possible* combination, or every *actual* combination *observed in the data*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be looking for `expand.grid` ?

```
R> expand.grid(var1, var2)
   Var1 Var2
1     1    1
2     2    1
3     3    1
4     4    1
5     5    1
6     6    1
7     7    1
8     8    1
9     9    1
10   10    1
11    1    6
12    2    6
13    3    6
14    4    6
15    5    6
16    6    6
17    7    6
18    8    6
19    9    6
20   10    6
```

Comment: And if you want to sort it like in your example: `require(plyr); arrange(as.data.frame(expand.grid(var1,var2)),Var1)`